# Bind system call on SUSE linux

Tags: linux, networking, posix, suse

On SUSE linux(Linux version 3.0.13-0.27), bind keyword in program might refer to system call "bind" as well as "bind" 3p function. I can see that my program is evaluating "bind" keyword to 3p function. I want to know whether can i force my program to evaluate bind keyword to "bind" system call.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same function with two specifications:

- `man 3 bind` shows the specification according to the POSIX standard
- `man 2 bin` shows the specification according to what Linux actually implements

> whether can i force my program to evaluate bind keyword to "bind"
>   system call

`bind` is not a keyword and your program is already calling the right system call.

Comment: I can see with return value that bind 3p is getting picked up. I want to pick up bind 2(which is a linux implementation). How can i achieve that.

Comment: @ManishSharanSingh What do you mean ? `bind` returns `int` according to both sections.

Comment: error code EAFNOSUPPORT to bind confirm that 3p is getting picked up as this error code is not available on bind 2.

Comment: @ManishSharanSingh What you are calling is `bind(2)`. They probably forgot to add that errno to the manual section; there's no way to call `bind(3p)` since that's just an abstract specification, not an actual implementation.